# Set DEFAULT_MAX_TO_STRING_FIELDS in Spark 2.2.0

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-spark

I want to change the value of the variable DEFAULT_MAX_TO_STRING_FIELDS in Spark 2.2.0 because I want to apply Machine Learning algorithms on data sets that have more than 25 features. The Apache Spark libraries are integrated in a Spring Boot application in the form of Maven dependencies thus I would like to change this property from code. I found an approach to display the number of features:

```
System.out.println(Utils.DEFAULT_MAX_TO_STRING_FIELDS());
```

but unfortunately I do not know how to change this value dynamically.

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below

```
SparkSession.conf.set("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", maxlength)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Next is presented the Java version: `SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Application Name").master("local[*]").getOrCreate(); spark.conf().set("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", maxLength);`